# formatting ticks on pyplot cmap loses the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the following code:-

```
fig=plt.figure()
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax=plt.axes()
font0 = FontProperties()

outgrid=[[x*y for x in range(testXaxis)] for y in range (levIndRange)]
vmin=0
vmax=testXaxis*levIndRange
height = [v*1000.5 for v in range (levMaxInd)]

colours='terrain'
cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap(colours)
norm=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(clip=False,vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
print 'vmax = ',vmax
m=plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap,norm=norm)  
m.set_array(outgrid)
plt.imshow(np.flipud(outgrid),cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect=stretch)
#ax.imshow(np.flipud(outgrid),cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect=stretch)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
#plt.axis.YAxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f')) # 'module' object has no attribute 'set_major_formatter'
plt.yticks([s for s in range(0,levIndRange,levParInt)],[height[v] for v in range(levMinInd-1,levMaxInd-1,levParInt)])
plt.xticks([1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19])
#ax.xaxis.set_ticks([1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19])
#ax.yaxis.set_ticks([height[v] for v in range(levMinInd-1,levMaxInd-1,levParInt)])    # This one line makes the plot collapse
plt.ylabel(yLabel)
plt.xlabel(xLabel)
```

I get the following plot, which is fine, but I want to change the floating point precision on the y-axis:-

[image: Plot with default floating precision]

So, when I try to alter the precision on the y-axis using set_major_formatter and the following lines instead of plot.yticks :-

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19])
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([height[v] for v in range(levMinInd-1,levMaxInd-1,levParInt)])    # This one line makes the plot collapse
```

... the plot disappears:-

[image: Plot with formatted floating precision]

How can I alter the precision without losing the plot?

Any help gratefully received.
Thanks

Comment: Asking about undesired behaviour only makes sense if a [mcve] of the issue is provided, i.e. a piece of code that can be copied and run to reproduce the issue. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering rather than editing because I have solved the lost plot problem, and that might be a help to someone else. The solution is to move the plt.imshow line AFTER the ax.yaxis.set_ticks line. However, I am still not getting the expected Y axis ticks with no decimal point.

The first block of code below produces a plot with Y ticks: 0.0,1000.5,2001.0,3001.5,4002.0

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
outgrid=[[x*y for x in range(4)] for y in range (5)]
height = [v*1000.5 for v in range (5)]
cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('terrain')
norm=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(clip=False)
m=plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap,norm=norm)  
m.set_array(outgrid)
plt.imshow(outgrid,cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect=0.5)
plt.yticks([s for s in range(5)],[height[t] for t in range(5)])
plt.show()
```

This second block of code tries to format these ticks with no decimal point but just produces one Y tick of 0

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
ax=plt.axes()
outgrid=[[x*y for x in range(4)] for y in range (5)]
height = [v*1000.5 for v in range (5)]
cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('terrain')
norm=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(clip=False)
m=plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap,norm=norm)  
m.set_array(outgrid)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([height[t] for t in range(5)])    
plt.imshow(outgrid,cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't really look like a solution. But if it is, it's probably not useful for others as one apparently needs to read the answer first to understand the question. For the ticks, it's pretty clear that if the image ranges from -0.5 to 4.5, setting the y ticks to something like 2000 is not very reasonable. Maybe you want to scale the image to the range of the values in your `height` array?